# I am a bit confuse about running a regression

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, finance, economics

I am a bit confuse about running a regression. Independent Variables are as:

X1 = Profitability Index
X2 = Operational Index
X3 = Cost per employee
X4 = Leverage Ratio

I am confused that can I use indexes and as well as single variables as independent variables in the regression.

Clarification needed!

Thanks

Comment: Could you give us some more details about what you are trying to do and your data?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unsure of what you mean by *single variables* - but I assume that you are referring to, on one hand, variables that consist of multiple variables, and, on the other hand, variables that have not been put together with other variables.

If the above is the case, then yes, you can both use index variables as well as single variables.

However, of cause you have to be aware that you cannot use any single variables that are part of any of the index variables, as this will bias your results and possibly overestimate the effect of some variables.